# Task host node exited prematurely Error. Log file location

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

[image]

For some time now I have trying to run a work project and recieving the following errors.
Clicking run again correctly builds the project and allows me to run. Using TFS I have now checked my work in and other collegues have taken a copy, now thier versions of Visual Studio are doing exactly the same.

Where is the MSBuild_*failure.txt written to as I (or they) can't seem to find it on our machines?

Better yet is there a known solution to stopping this behaviour?

The solution contains 6 projects, all written in VB.net, some projects are class librarys some windows applications.

Comment: Correspond to MSBuild only; VB.NET is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if you have MSBuild.exe processes running at the time of building.  MSBuild uses nodes that get reused by default.  This sometimes causes errors when building.  To turn it off, just specify /nodeReuse:false.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Comment: Terminating all MSBuildTaskHost.exe processes fixed my problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me with VS 2017 and i was getting frustrated. Fortunately i had another system with VS 2015, took my project there and it got successfully compiled there. Weird

Comment: Can you please explain where from i can turn off 
specify /nodeReuse:false ?